# Let $I \subseteq \Bbb R$ be a non-degenerate open interval

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

> Let $I \subseteq \Bbb R$ be a non-degenerate open interval, and let $n\in \Bbb N$.  Let $f:I\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=x^n$ for all $x\in I$.  Prove that $f$ is differentiable and $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$ for all $x\in I$

I am probably about to fail miserably, but here is my attempt:
$f'(x)=lim_{h\rightarrow 0}$${f(x+h)-f(x)}\over{h}$
So, for $f(x)=x^n$, $f'(x)=lim_{h\rightarrow 0}$${(x+h)^n-x^n}\over{h}$
At this point I get stuck because, depending on the value of n, $(x+h)^n$ can be a binomial, trinomial, ... n-nomial.

Comment: You are not going to fail as you are going in the right track; expand this carry out the division for the cases $n=2$, $n=3$, $n=4$, and then you will be able to see for the general $n$.

Comment: @PVanchinathan, n=2 : h+2x , n=3 : $h^2 + 3hx + 3x^2$ , n=4 : $h^3 + 4h^2 + 6hx^2 + 4x^3$, so I see the $nx^{n-1}$ term, but I am unsure how to get rid of the terms with h in them.

Comment: Since we are looking at the limit as $h \rightarrow 0$, then we can set h=0, thus all the terms with h cancel and we are left with the $nx^{n-1}$ term.  Correct?

Comment: First divide by $h$ (note the denominator in the definition of derivative as limit), and then set $h$ to zero.

Comment: You got it now. You can do this for $\sin x$ too, if you know the formula for $\sin(A+B)$, and get the derivative of $\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof suggested in the answer of @PVanchinathan is to use Newton's binomial theorem to expand the expression $(x+h)^n$.

Another method could be to use induction on $n$ and the product rule of differentiation: for the induction step, write $f$ with $f(x) = x^{n+1}$ as the product of $g$ and $h$ with $g(x) = x^n$ and $h(x) = x$.

According to the product rule for differentiation,
$$f'(x) = g'(x) h(x) + g(x) h'(x) = n x^{n-1} x + x^n \cdot 1 = (n+1) x^n.$$